# Getting Slim routes to work using grunt-contrib-connect and connect-modrewrite-jgchristian

Tags: gruntjs, url-rewriting, slim

I'm using [connect-modrewrite-jgchristian](https://github.com/jgchristian/connect-modrewrite) because it's supposed to hand the QSA flag properly. As of right now the index page works, but none of the internal pages do. Here's Slim's stock .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Using this directly will load the index page:

```
rewrite(['%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ^ index.php [QSA,L]'])
```

Trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:9000/news` throws a Cannot GET error:

```
Cannot GET /news
```

This works slightly better - it will load index.php when you go to `/news`, but the route doesn't get triggered:

```
rewrite(['!\\.php|\\.html|\\.js|\\.css|\\.svg|\\.jp(e?)g|\\.png|\\.gif$ /index.php [QSA,L]'])
```

Just for good measure, here's my Slim routes, although I'm pretty sure it's not getting this far:

```
$app->get('/', function () use($app, $smarty) {
   $app->render('home.tpl', array('ParentTemplate' => $smarty->compile_id . '.tpl'));
})->name('home');

$app->get('/news', function () use($app, $smarty) {
   $app->render('news.tpl', array('ParentTemplate' => $smarty->compile_id . '.tpl'));
})->name('news');
```

Anyone ever tried something like this? I'm stumped for the moment.

**UPDATE**

I figured out that it'll only work with the regex second example, but it still looks like it's not passing whatever info slim needs to access the proper route.

**UPDATE 2**

Got this tracked down to the way grunt-contrib-connect handles $_SERVER vars (I think). Here's regular apache:

```
'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '' (length=0)
'PATH_INFO' => string '/about' (length=6)
```

connect's server only has:

```
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>  string(1) "/"
```

Slim sets PATH_INFO to $requestUri, so figuring out how to set this in connect I think should solve the problem. Working on that now.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to grunt-php and all started working.